# Get height of a div dynamically created

Tags: jquery

i have create a div class=box via Ajax call and appended to an main  div.
This div class=box change its height based on its content. I need to have its height but  .height() return 0....

```
$.ajax({  url: "json/news.json",
      dataType: "json",  
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      success: function(data){
          var html ="<div class='box'>"+data.box+"</div>"; 
      } 
  });
 // now i want its height 
 var j = $('.box').height();
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like you are appending anything!? Could you also post the code you've written for appending the html into the main div?

Comment: @user: Are you using/appending `html` variable somewhere? Your current code doesn't show that.

Comment: Usually you can use Firefox plugin Firebug and debug all DOM variables value and properties. Use the keyword debugger in your JavaScript to trigger the debugger breakpoint. In this case you would notice that height() i called before success callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. `$.ajax` is asynchronous, so it does not create anything until the `success` callback has run.  If you want to measure your box, you will need to do it in the callback:

   ```
   $.ajax({  url: "json/news.json",
     dataType: "json",  
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
     success: function(data){
         var html ="<div class='box'>"+data.box+"</div>"; 
         var j = $('.box').height();
     } 
   });
   ```
2. You are not adding your html to anything, and as it is not part of the DOM it will not have a height.  You need to do something like the below:

   ```
   success: function(data){
     var html ="<div class='box'>"+data.box+"</div>"; 
     $("body").html(html);
     var j = $('.box').height();
   }
   ```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use it outside of the callback (at least, in the way you did in your original example), as it will not have a value.  What is it that you want to use `j` for?

Comment: I want use J to set height for other div. is it possible?

Comment: Yes - you just need to add `$("#otherDiv").height(j)` after the `var j=...` line in the second example

Comment: @ down voter - any comment on why you voted this answer down? Perhaps we could improve it?

Answer (score 2):

The last line of your code is executed *before* the ajax cal returns. Put the code that needs the height in the callback (and actually *add* the HTML to the document):

```
$.ajax({  url: "json/news.json",
      dataType: "json",  
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      success: function(data){
          var html ="<div class='box'>"+data.box+"</div>";
          var height = $(html).appendTo('body').height();
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

`var j = $('.box')outerHeight();`